# Why is the padding not applied on a div with a table inside?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html code here. I don't understand why the padding in the second DIV is not showing? If i remove the cellpadding and spacing, i see around 10 pixels in padding, but not the 20px i want.

Why?

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto; max-width: 860px;">
        <div style="border:1px solid #999; padding 20px; margin: 40px 10px; background: red;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="55"> xxx </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 14px;">xxx </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The width of your `table` is 100% of the parent, which has padding.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason.

You just forgot a `:` after `padding`

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto; max-width: 860px;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #999; padding: 20px; margin: 40px 10px; background: red;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="55">xxx</td>
                <td style="font-size: 14px;">xxx</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgGvU/)

Comment: Wow. I usually spot those errors pretty quick. Can't believe i just wasted a few hours on that. I hate programming ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The padding of the outer div is decreasing  the full padding  of the inner div. The padding of the outer div is 0px auto meaning it is padded to the center . Try using a padding of say 2px for the outer div to see the effect. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer DIV is the problem. It's minimizing the set padding in the inner DIV. However, why not set cellpadding to 10px?

Answer (score 0):

The width of your `table` is `100%` of its parent, which has padding.